# Retrieve the position (column name) of the maximum value of the derivative of an interval

Tags: r, dataframe, derivative

To calculate the Red Edge Position Index, I need to find the wavelength value (column name) corresponding to the maximum derivative of reflectance in the red edge region from 690nm to 740nm.  I have included a subset of my dataframe below, it contains the correct interval...

I have 640 rows (Sample) of 2151 measurements (values)  plus a few catagoricals in the first columns (e.g. plantType and plantCondition). I need to find the column of the value corresponding to the maximum of the derivative of the values in the interval specified and return the wavelength value to the REPI column.

I am trying something like this but I do not know how to calculate the maximum of the derivative in the specified interval

```
# find the maximum of the derivative of the values in columns x690:x740
# attempt to find for single sample first
> which( colnames(spec.data)=="X690")
[1] 352
> which( colnames(spec.data)=="X740")
[1] 402
# I want to return the values of the differential but this doesn't work
> foo.vector <- diff(spec.data[1,352:402])
>> Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

This makes sense because I don't have the dt in dx/dt but I am not sure how to retrieve the position of the maximum value of the derivative of this interval. once I did I think I would

```
> spec.data$REPI <- which( colnames(spec.data) == max(foo.vector))
```

Then I think I would lapply this for each row?

Can anyone point me towards a solution for this?
Thank you...

subset of data from dput

```
> dput(spec.data[1:2, c(1:3, 7, 300:450)])
structure(list(Sample = c("JUMO_G1 P1T9 Leaf Clip00000.asd", 
"JUMO_G1 P1T9 Leaf Clip00001.asd"), plantType = c("JUMO", "JUMO"
), plantCondition = c("G", "G"), REPI = c(NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    X638 = c(0.0611, 0.06114), X639 = c(0.0606, 0.06064), X640 = c(0.0601, 
    0.06012), X641 = c(0.0595, 0.05953), X642 = c(0.0589, 0.05893
    ), X643 = c(0.0584, 0.05834), X644 = c(0.0577, 0.05775), 
    X645 = c(0.05717, 0.05717), X646 = c(0.0566, 0.05664), X647 = c(0.0562, 
    0.05618), X648 = c(0.0557, 0.05573), X649 = c(0.0554, 0.05536
    ), X650 = c(0.0551, 0.05505), X651 = c(0.0547, 0.05475), 
    X652 = c(0.05448, 0.05447), X653 = c(0.0542, 0.05421), X654 = c(0.054, 
    0.05395), X655 = c(0.0536, 0.05357), X656 = c(0.0532, 0.05319
    ), X657 = c(0.0528, 0.05277), X658 = c(0.0523, 0.05229), 
    X659 = c(0.0518, 0.05176), X660 = c(0.05128, 0.05126), X661 = c(0.0508, 
    0.05077), X662 = c(0.0503, 0.05024), X663 = c(0.0498, 0.04978
    ), X664 = c(0.0494, 0.04936), X665 = c(0.049, 0.04897), X666 = c(0.04869, 
    0.04866), X667 = c(0.0484, 0.04838), X668 = c(0.0482, 0.04815
    ), X669 = c(0.048, 0.04797), X670 = c(0.0479, 0.04782), X671 = c(0.0478, 
    0.04775), X672 = c(0.0478, 0.04773), X673 = c(0.0478, 0.04773
    ), X674 = c(0.0478, 0.04776), X675 = c(0.0479, 0.04786), 
    X676 = c(0.0481, 0.04802), X677 = c(0.0483, 0.0482), X678 = c(0.0486, 
    0.04843), X679 = c(0.0489, 0.04873), X680 = c(0.04925, 0.04911
    ), X681 = c(0.0498, 0.04962), X682 = c(0.0504, 0.05026), 
    X683 = c(0.05122, 0.05103), X684 = c(0.0522, 0.052), X685 = c(0.0533, 
    0.05317), X686 = c(0.0548, 0.05458), X687 = c(0.05647, 0.05627
    ), X688 = c(0.0584, 0.05824), X689 = c(0.0608, 0.06057), 
    X690 = c(0.0634, 0.06326), X691 = c(0.0664, 0.06626), X692 = c(0.0698, 
    0.06958), X693 = c(0.0734, 0.07317), X694 = c(0.0773, 0.07701
    ), X695 = c(0.0814, 0.08109), X696 = c(0.0856, 0.0854), X697 = c(0.0901, 
    0.08989), X698 = c(0.0947, 0.09449), X699 = c(0.0994, 0.09917
    ), X700 = c(0.10417, 0.10395), X701 = c(0.10899, 0.10881), 
    X702 = c(0.11385, 0.11366), X703 = c(0.11871, 0.11854), X704 = c(0.12356, 
    0.12342), X705 = c(0.1284, 0.12829), X706 = c(0.13324, 0.13312
    ), X707 = c(0.13803, 0.13792), X708 = c(0.14281, 0.14273), 
    X709 = c(0.14763, 0.14755), X710 = c(0.15243, 0.15235), X711 = c(0.15718, 
    0.15713), X712 = c(0.16192, 0.16189), X713 = c(0.1667, 0.16663
    ), X714 = c(0.17143, 0.17137), X715 = c(0.17609, 0.17605), 
    X716 = c(0.18069, 0.18062), X717 = c(0.18528, 0.1852), X718 = c(0.18977, 
    0.18968), X719 = c(0.19417, 0.19406), X720 = c(0.19851, 0.19838
    ), X721 = c(0.20276, 0.20263), X722 = c(0.20686, 0.20671), 
    X723 = c(0.2108, 0.21063), X724 = c(0.21465, 0.21449), X725 = c(0.21837, 
    0.21819), X726 = c(0.22194, 0.22174), X727 = c(0.22534, 0.22515
    ), X728 = c(0.2286, 0.22838), X729 = c(0.23164, 0.23142), 
    X730 = c(0.23447, 0.23427), X731 = c(0.23719, 0.23696), X732 = c(0.23984, 
    0.23959), X733 = c(0.24229, 0.24203), X734 = c(0.24452, 0.24426
    ), X735 = c(0.24668, 0.24638), X736 = c(0.24867, 0.24839), 
    X737 = c(0.25053, 0.25028), X738 = c(0.25229, 0.25203), X739 = c(0.25382, 
    0.25359), X740 = c(0.25531, 0.25508), X741 = c(0.25672, 0.25646
    ), X742 = c(0.25791, 0.25766), X743 = c(0.25907, 0.25884), 
    X744 = c(0.26014, 0.25993), X745 = c(0.2611, 0.26089), X746 = c(0.26201, 
    0.26178), X747 = c(0.26278, 0.26257), X748 = c(0.26347, 0.26329
    ), X749 = c(0.26414, 0.26397), X750 = c(0.26475, 0.26459), 
    X751 = c(0.26525, 0.2651), X752 = c(0.26568, 0.26554), X753 = c(0.26614, 
    0.266), X754 = c(0.26652, 0.26639), X755 = c(0.26682, 0.26671
    ), X756 = c(0.2671, 0.26701), X757 = c(0.26743, 0.26734), 
    X758 = c(0.26767, 0.26758), X759 = c(0.26789, 0.26781), X760 = c(0.26814, 
    0.26808), X761 = c(0.2682, 0.26817), X762 = c(0.26835, 0.26831
    ), X763 = c(0.26856, 0.26851), X764 = c(0.26872, 0.26869), 
    X765 = c(0.26884, 0.26881), X766 = c(0.26892, 0.2689), X767 = c(0.26896, 
    0.26894), X768 = c(0.26898, 0.26896), X769 = c(0.2691, 0.26909
    ), X770 = c(0.2692, 0.2692), X771 = c(0.26921, 0.26921), 
    X772 = c(0.26923, 0.26926), X773 = c(0.26927, 0.26931), X774 = c(0.26935, 
    0.26939), X775 = c(0.26945, 0.26947), X776 = c(0.26946, 0.26949
    ), X777 = c(0.26948, 0.26952), X778 = c(0.26953, 0.26958), 
    X779 = c(0.26958, 0.26963), X780 = c(0.26965, 0.2697), X781 = c(0.2697, 
    0.26975), X782 = c(0.2697, 0.26977), X783 = c(0.26972, 0.26978
    ), X784 = c(0.26979, 0.26982), X785 = c(0.26987, 0.2699), 
    X786 = c(0.26991, 0.26998), X787 = c(0.26989, 0.26997), X788 = c(0.26991, 
    0.26998)), .Names = c("Sample", "plantType", "plantCondition", 
"REPI", "X638", "X639", "X640", "X641", "X642", "X643", "X644", 
"X645", "X646", "X647", "X648", "X649", "X650", "X651", "X652", 
"X653", "X654", "X655", "X656", "X657", "X658", "X659", "X660", 
"X661", "X662", "X663", "X664", "X665", "X666", "X667", "X668", 
"X669", "X670", "X671", "X672", "X673", "X674", "X675", "X676", 
"X677", "X678", "X679", "X680", "X681", "X682", "X683", "X684", 
"X685", "X686", "X687", "X688", "X689", "X690", "X691", "X692", 
"X693", "X694", "X695", "X696", "X697", "X698", "X699", "X700", 
"X701", "X702", "X703", "X704", "X705", "X706", "X707", "X708", 
"X709", "X710", "X711", "X712", "X713", "X714", "X715", "X716", 
"X717", "X718", "X719", "X720", "X721", "X722", "X723", "X724", 
"X725", "X726", "X727", "X728", "X729", "X730", "X731", "X732", 
"X733", "X734", "X735", "X736", "X737", "X738", "X739", "X740", 
"X741", "X742", "X743", "X744", "X745", "X746", "X747", "X748", 
"X749", "X750", "X751", "X752", "X753", "X754", "X755", "X756", 
"X757", "X758", "X759", "X760", "X761", "X762", "X763", "X764", 
"X765", "X766", "X767", "X768", "X769", "X770", "X771", "X772", 
"X773", "X774", "X775", "X776", "X777", "X778", "X779", "X780", 
"X781", "X782", "X783", "X784", "X785", "X786", "X787", "X788"
), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: my guess would be that `which.max(unlist(diff(spec.data[1,352:402])))` would work, but haven't tested (the `unlist()` is the key - rows of data frames are lists, not vectors ...)

Comment: still seeing `Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator` i think it needs to be `diff(...)/diff(...)` but I dont know how to step the denominator.. I dont have  a time variable for example... tried `.../diff(1:(402-352))` but still the same error

Comment: Try putting `unlist` inside diff: `which.max(diff(unlist(spec.data[1,5:155])))`

Comment: That does work! thank you. The remaining question is: is that the location of the true maximum of the derivative of the series and not just the largest interval? if there is no noise in the interval values than this would be the answer for sure... is there a way I can account for this?

Comment: @ZiaRanks Is there a way for you to figure out the interval values? Also, take a look at the answer below using `apply` so that you don't have to repeat the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
spec.data$REPI <- apply(spec.data[,-(1:4)], 1, function(x) which.max(diff(x)))
```

Or you can try using  `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
spec.data %>%
    gather(key, value, -Sample, -plantType, - plantCondition, -REPI) %>%
    group_by(Sample) %>%
    summarise(which.max(diff(value)))
```

They both seem to give same results.

Comment: gather is from tidyr... got it.     This does work, I am still trying to figure out if the max difference is actually the maximum of the derivative though... (noise in step-wise values)

Comment: accepting this answer as it does provide a great solution provided there is no noise in the data. Thank you @parksw3

Comment: @ZiaRanks Another alternative is to use `melt` from `reshape2` package instead of `gather` but that's up to you... It seems like base R approach is simpler in this case though... I'm not sure how I would deal with noise... Hopefully, someone else can answer that...